# Derivative result changes when expanding sigma notation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm having some confusion over how to properly take derivatives of expressions involving a sum. Let a and b be 1 x n and n x 1 dimensional vectors, respectively. I want to take the partial derivative with respect to the jth component of vector b, $b_j$. It seems I get different results when I expand the sum, so I want to know what my mistake is.

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial b_j }\sum_{i=1}^Na_ib_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\partial }{\partial b_j }({ a_ib_i^2}) = \sum_{i=1}^N2a_jb_j = 2Na_jb_j$$

Compared with

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial b_j }\sum_{i=1}^Na_ib_i^2 = \frac{\partial }{\partial b_j }{(a_1b_1^2 + a_2b_2^2 + ... + a_nb_n^2)} =  \frac{\partial }{\partial b_j }{(a_jb_j^2)} = 2a_jb_j$$

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b_i$ is a component of an $N$-vector, then you can't simplify $\sum_{i=1}^N b_i = Nb_i$ because you don't actually have $N$ multiples of a single value, you have $N$ distinct values.

---

In light of comments, the actual problem is closely related but not quite as above.

The problem is actually that this is invalid: $$ \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\partial }{\partial b_j }({ a_ib_i^2}) = \sum_{i=1}^N2a_jb_j$$

You are converting the sum of (transformations of) all of components across the vector $b$ into a sum of multiple copies of a *single* component, which is not valid.

Comment: Mine was a bit different tho. I had $\sum_{i=1}^{N}b_j$ so the iterator was different. Then in that case it will just be $b_j$?

Comment: Both versions start with $b_i$, which is possibly a typo.

Comment: I don't understand. I was summing over all the components using the iterator i, but I only want the derivative with respect to the jth component of b

Comment: Ooooh, sorry, I was thinking you were trying to take a partial derivative somehow. Are any of the non-$j$ components of $b$ dependent on the $j$th component? Otherwise I don't see how either version you've written works

Comment: no, none of the non j components are dependent on the jth componenet

Comment: I have edited my answer to point to what I think the actual problem is, does that help?

Comment: I think that helps. So then would there be no way to get the derivative of this without writing out each term explicitly like I did in my second derivation?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to write it out, you just need to be aware that $\frac{db_i}{db_j}$ is $0$ for $i \neq j$ (AFAIK, I might be wrong about that) so most of the sum just vanishes regardless of whether you add the sums of derivatives or differentiate the sum.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b_3}(a_1b_1^2)$ seems like it should be $0$, not $2a_3b_3$ as the middle equals sign of the calculation in your top row would imply.

Separately, it sounds weird to take partial derivatives with respect to $b_j$ in the first place if $b_j$ is a vector. You would take a partial derivative with respect to a variable $y$, not, say, the vector $\langle0,1,0\rangle^\top$.

Comment: by $b_j$, I mean't the jth component of vector b